# SQL: How to link two tables that don't share a column name without creating a composite table?

Tags: sql, database, create-table

I have to create a database named "Elections" and then write some queries to get the answers provided by my teacher.
I created the database. My issue is that I don't know how to link two tables (candidate and constituency) because they do not share any primary or foreign key.
The teacher is saying that a composite table should not be created in order to link those two tables.
Please see picture (the tables are linked on the pictures but I do not know how to do it when I create the database).
I am also including:

- the query that I have to write. The thing is, without knowing how to link those two tables, I cannot write the query.
- the SQL code representing the creation of those two tables.

[image]

QUERY:
*1. Display the number of candidates eliminated in the first*
round, for each constituency, and show the constituency number,
and name.

SQL CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (
    CANDIDATE_NB smallint CONSTRAINT PK_CANDIDATE_NB PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PARTY_NB smallint NOT NULL,
    ROUND tinyint NOT NULL
);

alter table CANDIDATE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PARTY_NB FOREIGN KEY (PARTY_NB) REFERENCES PARTY(PARTY_NB);

CREATE TABLE CONSTITUENCY (
    CONSTITUENCY_NB smallint IDENTITY (100, 100) CONSTRAINT PK_CONSTITUENCY_NB PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    CONSTITUENCY_NAME varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    NB_REGISTERED smallint NULL,
    TOTAL_CANDIDATES smallint NULL
);
```

I am trying to understand how to link those two tables but I really can't think of anything apart from creating a composite table, which is not what has to be done as per my teacher's instructions.

Comment: *"Display the number of candidates eliminated in the first round, for each constituency, and show the constituency number, and name."* suggest that a `constituency` can have more than 1 `candidate`. I'm guessing, also, that the reverse is NOT true (that a `candidate` does NOT have many constituencies). If that's the case, then the `candidate` table should have `continuency_nb` column added to it to maintain the relationship. Or to put it another way "Constituency is an attribute of a Candidate and so it should be a column on the Candidate table".

Comment: I do not understand how candidate_nb has a one to many relationship with total_candidates? Some mistake here?

Comment: A candidate is a candidate **for** something... i.e. a constituency. You need (as already noted by JNevil) to add a column in the candidate table  for continuency_nb (as a  foreign key)